# Why bother to limit the types imported from a python package?

Tags: python

When using many IDEs that support autocompletion with Python, things like this will show warnings, which I find annoying:

```
from eventlet.green.httplib import BadStatusLine
```

When switching to:

```
from eventlet.green.httplib import *
```

The warnings go away. What's the benefit to limiting imports to a specific set of types you'll use? Is the parsing faster? Reduces collisions? What other point is there? It seems the state of python IDEs and the nature of the typing system makes it hard for many IDEs to fully get right when a type import works and when it doesn't.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import

Answer (score 4):

By typing `from foo import *`, you import *all* the names defined in `foo` into the global namespace. This is bad practice because you could have name clashes both with other modules and with built-ins.

For example, consider a module `foo`

```
#foo.py
def open(something):
    pass
```

and a module `bar`:

```
#bar.py
def open(something_else):
    pass
```

Now, `from foo import *` hides the built-in function `open()` which means that any calls to `open()` now refer to `foo.open()` rather than the built-in. Worse, if you then have `from bar import *`, the function `open()` in `bar` now hides both the built-in *and* the function imported from `foo`.

In the example above, `from foo import open` is equally shadowing the built-in function, but one glance at the code tells you why you can't open files for IO anymore.

This is why you should import only specific names, ensuring that you *know* what names are imported. Alternatively, you could use fully qualified names (`import foo; foo.open()`, which is perfectly safe).

EDIT: Just as a note, this can be horribly compounded if the module you're importing also uses `from x import *`. In this case, not only do you typically import all the stuff in the module `foo`, but also all the stuff in the module `x` into the global namespace. This can very quickly turn into an absolute mess.

Answer (score 1):

It reduces collisions with user-defined types, it reduces coupling and it's self-documenting, since it makes clear from the outset of the module which classes are coming from libraries (so the rest must be user-defined). The parsing is not faster, at least not in CPython: an imported module must be read in its entirety to look for the classes/functions being imported.

(I must admit that I never use an IDE.)

Comment: @Josh: I never use IDEs in general, I haven't even bothered to check out any for Python. Command line all the way :)

Comment: For languages like C# on .NET, I couldn't imagine NOT using Visual Studio.

Comment: Unfortunately you **need** an IDE for some python projects. http://indico-software.org/ is a good example (tons of inheritance and files - pretty much impossible to work with without an IDE)

Comment: @ThiefMaster: You still don't necessarily need a full-blown IDE. Something like vim with taglist allows you to navigate easily without the bloat and crap that comes with a full IDE.